# Compare arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary, enumerator

I have an array of fully qualified domain names:

```
["filer1.abc.com", filer2.abc.com, filer3.xyz.com]
```

I have another array that has hostnames:

```
["filer1", "filer3"]
```

I have to compare the two arrays, and if the hostnames are present in fqdn, then I need to get the fqdn from the first array. For example, `"filer1"` is present in `"filer1.abc.com"`, so I need to get the value `"filer1.abc.com"`. And `"filer3"` is present in `"filer3.xyz.com"`, so I need to get the value `"filer3.xyz.com"`.

Help is appreciated.

```
["filer1.abc.com", filer2.abc.com, filer3.xyz.com].map.each_with_index {|vserver, indx| vserver.id.include? host_names[indx] unless host_names[indx].nil?}}
```

I get `[true, nil, nil, nil]`, but I actually need the values of fqdn like `["filer1.abc.com"]`.

Comment: A select in place of map sounds like what you're looking for

Comment: What are `filer2` and `filer3`? What do the methods `abc`, `xyz`, and `com` do?

Comment: Translation from sawanese: if "filer2.abc.com" and "filer3.xyz.com" are strings they need to be in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fqdn_array = ["filer1.abc.com", "filer2.abc.com", "filer3.xyz.com"]
hostnames = ["filer1", "filer3"]

result = fqdn_array.keep_if{|fqdn| (hostnames - fqdn.split('.')).length < hostnames.length}
# => ["filer1.abc.com", "filer3.xyz.com"]
```

`Array#keep_if` iterates through the array and keeps all elements where the block is true. In the block I split your fqdn at the dot into an array. Then I subtract it from the hostnames array. If the result is shorter than the original array length, I found a fqdn which includes one of your hostnames and the condition returns true.

Comment: I think using `include?` would make things more readable   `fqdn_array.keep_if{|fqdn| hostnames.include? fqdn.split('.')[0] }`

Comment: You're welcome. If it's the right solution for you then accept this answer please.

Comment: @thomas-haratyk: My solution would work as well, if there's a fqdn like "abc.filer1.com".